# Find lim for $\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$
>   $$a_n:=\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n,k\in\mathbb N$$

My work:

I write it as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left[ \frac{1}{k} \cdot k \cdot \left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n}\right) \right]^n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{k}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^n}=0\cdot e^k=0$$

Can someone tell me whether my attempt is on the right track?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: What if $k = 1$?

Comment: Provided $k>1,$ this looks fine. Another argument: For $k>1,$ when $n$ is sufficiently large, $1/k+1/n<2/3,$ so for such $n,$ $(1/k+1/n)^{n}\leq(2/3)^{n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$

Comment: As others noticed, it's only valid for $k>1$.

Comment: For $k=1$, the limit will approach $e$. For $k\ge 1$, I believe it will approach $0$ (Havent confirmed)